# Do I need "Git" for Apache Spark installation

Tags: git, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, installation

I'm quite new to big data tech and trying to learn.
I followed an instruction to install Spark on Amazon-EC2, I made it but one of the steps made me confused and I couldn't find any reliable reason for "Installing Git" step.

Does Spark need Git for installation, if yes for what? What's the task for Git? 
If no, is there any reason to put it in installation guide?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No! You only need to install `curl` to install `spark` on AWS EC2.

Comment: probably if you want to clone the latest code and build it yourself. There are pre-built versions available as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: *No, you don't need Git to install Apache Spark*.

Longer answer: *There are ways, that already automate the installation for you.*

If you'd like to learn Apache Spark, the best way to start playing with Spark on AWS is [Databricks Community Edition](https://community.cloud.databricks.com/). Or just normal Databricks managed Spark clusters. They get [relatively small fee](https://databricks.com/product/aws-pricing) to take operational burden away.

The other way is to use [Amazon Elastic MapReduce](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html) with Spark/Zeppelin pre-installed by [ticking necessary boxes in user interface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=UbkucQ2EOXg) (or just your CloudFormation or Terraform scripts).

Though, Spark can really do [run on your laptop](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f) on very small datasets if you already have python/java installed on your box as described in this tutorial - .

Your mileage may vary.